# I am struggling to remove the last 30 characters from data in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am looking to remove the last 30 characters from a colum within my database.

```
Column Name = gatewayid
Table Name = tblclients
```

I have created the below which works in the sense it shows me the result and it's correct but it does not commit or change anything.

```
SELECT gatewayid, /* ANSI Syntax */SUBSTRING( gatewayid
FROM 1 
FOR CHAR_LENGTH( gatewayid ) -30 ) AS col_trimmed, /* MySQL Syntax */SUBSTRING( gatewayid, 1, CHAR_LENGTH( gatewayid ) -30 ) AS col_trimmed
FROM tblclients
```

What am I missing, I am a noob :)

I expect the data in the column to remove the last 30 characters from each row.

Comment: SELECT only retrieves data, in cannot change it, only how it is relayed. You need an UPDATE to change existing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `update` statement:

```
update tblclients 
set gatewayid = substring( gatewayid, 1, char_length( gatewayid ) -30 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
SELECT gatewayid
,/*ANSI Syntax*/ SUBSTRING(gatewayid FROM 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(gatewayid) - 30) col_trimmed_ansi
,/* MySQL Syntax*/ SUBSTRING(gatewayid, 1  CHAR_LENGTH(gatewayid) -30) AS col_trimmed_mysql
FROM tblclients
```

and for update the table content

```
  UPDATE tblclients
  set gatewayid = SUBSTRING(gatewayid FROM 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(gatewayid) - 30)
```